# Failing to start Replicated ZooKeeper with Ansible and Docker

Tags: docker, ansible, apache-zookeeper

I have been able to deploy ZooKeeper with Docker in standalone mode, running a single ZooKeeper container, but I'm now trying to deploy three containerized ZooKeepers with Ansible and cannot seem to get the system to start in replicated mode.

I am using a [well supported](https://docs.docker.com/samples/library/zookeeper/) Docker version of ZooKeeper, and have tried setting the `ZOO_MY_ID` and `ZOO_SERVERS` as the docs suggest, although when trying to deploy the containers they very quickly fail with an `Invalid config` error, and also seem to have not set the `myid` variable required for the replicated mode.

The errors are of the form below, and you'll see also that the address of some of the other servers cannot be resolved (although I can ssh into these machines just fine, and Ansible successfully deploys to each - its just the containers are stuck in a crashing loop).

From the docker logs:

```
Using config: /conf/zoo.cfg
2019-08-22 07:07:22,188 [myid:] - INFO  [main:QuorumPeerConfig@133] - Reading configuration from: /conf/zoo.cfg
2019-08-22 07:07:22,192 [myid:] - INFO  [main:QuorumPeerConfig@375] - clientPort is not set
2019-08-22 07:07:22,192 [myid:] - INFO  [main:QuorumPeerConfig@389] - secureClientPort is not set
2019-08-22 07:07:22,198 [myid:] - ERROR [main:QuorumPeerMain@89] - Invalid config, exiting abnormally
org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumPeerConfig$ConfigException: Address unresolved: hostname3:3888"
    at org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumPeer$QuorumServer.<init>(QuorumPeer.java:279)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.flexible.QuorumMaj.<init>(QuorumMaj.java:89)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumPeerConfig.createQuorumVerifier(QuorumPeerConfig.java:595)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumPeerConfig.parseDynamicConfig(QuorumPeerConfig.java:628)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumPeerConfig.setupQuorumPeerConfig(QuorumPeerConfig.java:601)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumPeerConfig.parseProperties(QuorumPeerConfig.java:420)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumPeerConfig.parse(QuorumPeerConfig.java:150)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumPeerMain.initializeAndRun(QuorumPeerMain.java:113)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumPeerMain.main(QuorumPeerMain.java:82)
Invalid config, exiting abnormally
```

I am struggling to understand why the `[myid:]` box is missing the variable I'm setting, and why the address of this other host can't be resoled.

I was wondering if they're each trying to start and reach out to the other servers but given that none are running, they all fail. This feels almost too ridiculous to be the problem though, so I'm assuming I've made a mistake in the config somewhere.

I've tried various versions of the Ansible deployment below (where I'm just showing one of the three, but they all follow the same pattern), trying things like the fully-qualified names or public IPs for the other ZooKeeper hosts, `0.0.0.0` and `zookeeper` for the local host, and a number of different things - all without success.

```
- name: Deploy ZooKeeper1
  hosts: zk1
  ...
  tasks:
    - docker_service:
        project_name: zk
        definition:
          version: '3'
          services:
            zookeeper:
              image: zookeeper:latest
              hostname: "zookeeper"
              environment:
                - ALLOW_ANONYMOUS_LOGIN="yes"
                - ZOO_MY_ID=1
                - ZOO_SERVERS="server.1=zookeeper:2888:3888 server.2=hostname2:2888:3888 server.3=hostname3:2888:3888"
              restart: always
              ports:
                - "2181:2181" # port for clients, including Kafka
                - "2888:2888" # port for ZooKeeper to connect to other ZooKeeper peers to coordinate
                - "3888:3888" # port for leader election
```

Comment: If you are using zookeeper 3.5 then the syntax for `ZOO_SERVERS` has changed. See https://docs.docker.com/samples/library/zookeeper (`server.id=<address1>:<port1>:<port2>[:role];[<client port address>:]<client port>`)

Comment: Thanks a lot - I should mention I've attempted that too actually - with ZOO_SERVERS set to something of the form `ZOO_SERVERS: server.1=0.0.0.0:2888:3888;2181 server.2=hostname2:2888:3888;2181 server.3=hostname3:2888:3888;2181`.   In this case the error message is similar but with the unresolved address as  ` Address unresolved: 0.0.0.0:2181`

Answer (score 5):

pay attention to any spaces or other invisible char in config file, for example: a space after 3888

Comment: there was a space indeed. Thank you for saving the day